# How to reduce the size of a SQL Server-Database?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, database-size

### Context

We have a Backup DB, where we normally store BackUps of tables from production DB before doing any updates/deletes. If anything goes wrong, we can restore the data from that table created in BackUp DB.

### Problem

The size of Backup DB is rapidly increasing and **I need a way to reduce its size**.

#### Steps so far

I tried deleting old tables and shrinking BackUP DB but shrinking takes too much of time.

Comment: Have you considered [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Another option is to use columnstore clustered indexes in BackupDB. If your tables are big (several millions records +), it may save a lot of space.
Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [table / index compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-ver15) to see if your tables can be better compressed in the `BackUp` database?

You can use the system stored procedure [`sp_estimate_data_compression_savings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to roughly calculate how much space you can save by compressing your tables / indexes.

Also, if you don't need to save older data in your `BackUp` database, you should delete it when possible (perhaps after you're done making your data changes to the main table and it's verified as ok?). By doing so, you'll free up space that can be re-used in the `BackUp` database to proactively prevent it from growing as much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time event or does it happen again? I.e., is this "copy" database used over time to store old copies of data? If so, then why would you want to pay dearly to reclaim storage when you end up needing this storage again the next day or week? The reasoning is the same as for why we don't shrink data or log files in general.

Yes, there are of course compression options you can use so this copy don't need as much space. They have already been suggested (clustered columnstore index possibly with archival compression and data compression). Evaluate those options and then just be fine with the disk requirement for your copy-database. :-)

Comment: It is a repeated process as we use this DB to copy table information from production DB.

Comment: Then just leave it to the size it is, and consider using whatever compression technique you feel comfortable with (clustered columnstore index or data compression). I.e., don't shrink the database files between your repeated runs (except for the initial shrink to a more reasonable size after changing to use a compression technique).